# Stacktrace in flutter/dart is missing

Tags: flutter, dart

Often when developing in flutter, I get errors like this (in the VSCode debug console):

[image]

How do I find where these errors are happening? Sometimes it does actually give me a location.

Comment: You can search in your packages or use Google - it's coming from https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart line 166

Comment: Hint: stop doing this: `try { ... } catch  (e) { print('error is $e'); }`  If you aren't going to FULLY HANDLE the error, do not CATCH THE ERROR.  (rethrow would be ok).

Comment: @RandalSchwartz yes good point but this is coming from a package @Richard yes I didn't really think of googling it. I want this to work for all print statements though. sometimes i absent-mindedly `print(res)` without any hardcoded marker to identify it, and forget about it for weeks. the resulting call to print is very hard to find

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes errors are suppressed by **try-catch** methods, to prevent error propagation through the code, and to allow the following processes to continue.

There are multiple ways to discover what segment of your code is creating the error.

There is a simple and popular method of using **print** functions alongside your code calls, to try to locate the problematic component, or function call.

A more advanced approach is to use **debug**. But first is necessary to have a clue of the error origin, before running the code line by line until you find the exact problematic call.